Deep Linking Issue in a MAUI Android Application: ClassNotFoundException
I’m trying to implement Deep Linking in my MAUI Android application to handle ed2k links. However, when I click on an ed2k link and select my application to open it, I get the following error:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.test_maui/com.mycompany.test_maui.test_maui.MainActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mycompany.test_maui.test_maui.MainActivity" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.test_maui-xpJaFrKRoLluech0atEfZQ==/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycompany.test_maui-xpJaFrKRoLluech0atEfZQ==/lib/arm64,
/data/app/com.mycompany.test_maui-xpJaFrKRoLluech0atEfZQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /prets/lib64]]

I’ve tried several solutions, including making sure the namespace in MainActivity.cs matches what’s specified in AndroidManifest.xml. Here’s the relevant code from my AndroidManifest.xml file and my MainActivity.cs file:
AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mycompany.test_maui">
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="ed2k" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>

MainActivity.cs:
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;

namespace test_maui
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Check if the activity was started from a link
            if (Android.Content.Intent.ActionView.Equals(Intent.Action))
            {
                // Get the link
                var elink = Intent.DataString;

                // Display a message on screen with the link
                Toast.MakeText(this, "ed2k Link: " + elink, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}

I was expecting that, upon clicking an ed2k link, my application would open and display a message on screen with the link. However, instead, I get the aforementioned error.
I hope this helps you answer the questions.


Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.test_maui/com.mycompany.test_maui.test_maui.MainActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.mycompany.test_maui.test_maui.MainActivity"

On Xamarin.Android, by default, generates the Java wrappers using MD5-based class names to avoid Java class name clashing, such as:
 md579731053346ff64fcf21847b09163ce1.MainActivity 

You have hard-coded a activity android:name=".MainActivity" in your manifest but the generated class will be MD5-based by default.
You should avoid to mix up declarative attributes and manually writing the AndroidManifest.xml.
[Activity (Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher")] is generating a piece of code in the actual used (generated) AndroidManifest.xml that looks like:
  <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="AndroidApp1" android:name="md5c178831cd46fc53bebc42cf953f78ced.MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

and your code will be somewhere else. You can find the generated AndroidManifest.xml in the output folder .\obj\Debug\android.
So,try to remove the manual edits from your manifest file and add your stuff via attributes if you need.
For example:
[Activity(Label = "Demos", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,Exported =true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)] 
    [
    IntentFilter
    (
        new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
            {
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
            },
        DataSchemes = new[] { "myapp" }
    )
]
    public class MainActivity:Activity
 {

 }


Just wanted to say your advice worked like a charm. Really appreciate it!

Glad to be able to help you. Have a nice day. :)

I don't think you're setting up the App Link correctly inside your AndroidManifest.xml file.
First and foremost, you are only declaring a very general ed2k schema type, and no host to associate with it.  While only declaring a schema is not particularly wrong, it seems that your declaration could be a lot more specific by explicitly expecting a particular website for the app link.
Next, you're missing the top-level android:autoVerify="true" filter attribute, which will allow the OS to better handle your app link overall.
Before moving on, I would invite you to read over the official documentation to better familiarize yourself with the process.
Last but not least, there is also a very useful Android Studio panel that will help you not only create your App Links, but verify them as well directly in your IDE.  Here's some more documentation on the topic.
With all of that said, here's how I would expect your intent-filter declaration to look once you make the required adjustments:
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="ed2k" />
  <data android:host="<your_website_goes_here" />
</intent-filter>

Before closing this out, I'd like to point out that you'll have to declare your App Links inside the Play Console once they get published into the production env as well, and here is yet more documentation on the matter.

Thank you for your time and effort in responding to my question. However, there seems to have been a misunderstanding. ed2k links are not associated with a specific website, so I don’t need to specify a host in my intent filter.
ed2k links are used by the eDonkey2000 network (and also by its derivative, eMule) to share files.For example, an ed2k link might look like this: ed2k://|file|example.txt|123456789|0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef|/
I’d also like to point out that I’m developing my app in Visual Studio 2022, not Android Studio.
Thank you again for your help.

Granted.  But you're still missing the autoVerify attr, and I'm also recommending you take a look at Android Studio's App Link Assistant tool in order to create and/or verify your app links.  I'm sure you should be able to find you answer out of that.

I appreciate your suggestions. I’ve already tried adding the autoVerify attribute, but unfortunately, I’m still getting the same error. As for the App Link Assistant tool, I will definitely look into it. Thank you again for your help
